# How can I define a default subcommand in Rust Clap?

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, clap

I'm building a CLI in Rust to learn the language and I am using [clap](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap) with the derive feature for the argument parsing. I would like to have a specific behavior of my CLI; specifically, it has some subcommands, and I want to execute one in particular (`To`) when not specified.

The code is this:

```rs
use clap::{Args, Parser, Subcommand};

#[derive(Parser)]
#[command(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
#[command(propagate_version = true)]
struct Cli {
    #[command(subcommand)]
    command: Commands,
}

#[derive(Subcommand)]
enum Commands {
    /// Goes to the reference
    To(GotoArgs),
    /// Adds reference to the json file
    Add(AddArgs),
    /// Deletes a reference in the json file
    Del(DelArgs),
    /// Lists all the references in the json file
    List,
}
```

I want my program to execute the `to` subcommand when no other commands are specified, and take the `GotoArgs`. How can I achieve this behavior?

Another way would be to define the parser as an `enum`, in order to say, for example, choose a command from `Commands` or take the arguments for the (implicit) `To` command. The problem is that I don't find a lot in the documentation and I don't know how and if I can do it.

**EDIT:** I want to be able to launch the program with `binary GotoArgs`, so with the possibility to omit the `to` subcommand.

Comment: See https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/issues/975

Comment: @Sprite I saw that, but I think there is a slightly different behavior from mines. I want to be able to write `binary GotoArgs`, omitting the `to` subcommand, and the solutions don't work in my case or are for different scenarios

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with clap. It would create ambiguities.

Consider the following code:

```rust
use clap::{Args, Parser, Subcommand};

#[derive(Parser)]
#[command(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
#[command(propagate_version = true)]
struct Cli {
    #[command(subcommand)]
    command: Commands,
}

#[derive(Args)]
struct GotoArgs {
    val: String,
}

#[derive(Args)]
struct AddArgs {}

#[derive(Args)]
struct DelArgs {}

#[derive(Subcommand)]
enum Commands {
    /// Goes to the reference
    To(GotoArgs),
    /// Adds reference to the json file
    Add(AddArgs),
    /// Deletes a reference in the json file
    Del(DelArgs),
    /// Lists all the references in the json file
    List,
}
```

If `To(GoToArgs)` would now be the default, what would the following be?

```
./myapp add
```

Would that create this:

```
Cli {
   command: Commands::To(GotoArgs{
      val: "add"
   })
}
```

or this?

```
Cli {
   command: Commands::Add(AddArgs{})
}
```

Comment: it could depend on the library implementation. In a case like this, they could have implemented the default behavior to be the one in the command "add", or maybe if it has errors it could take it as a parameter. I don't know, but for sure there are ambiguities

Comment: Well, I don't know for sure, but from my understanding, one of the goals of clap was to have zero ambiguities. Be aware that while clap is absolutely excellent and I do recommend it strongly, it **is** opinionated. You can't create every possible combination of command line arguments with it.